# jquery: how to get the value of id attribute?

Tags: jquery

Basic jquery question. I have an option element as below.

```
<option class='select_continent' value='7'>Antarctica</option>
```

jquery

```
$(".select_continent").click(function () {
  alert(this.attr('value'));
});
```

This gives an error saying this.attr is not a function so im not using "this" correctly.

How can i get it to alert 7?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You need to do:

```
alert($(this).attr('value'));
```

Comment: I like @Mottie answer better :) Much simpler!

Answer (score 70):

To match the title of this question, the value of the `id` attribute is:

```
var myId = $(this).attr('id');
alert( myId );
```

BUT, of course, the element must already have the id element defined, as:

```
<option id="opt7" class='select_continent' value='7'>Antarctica</option>
```

In the OP post, this was not the case.

---

#### IMPORTANT:

**Note that** plain js is faster (in this case):

```
var myId = this.id
alert(  myId  );
```

*That is, if you are just storing the returned text into a variable as in the above example. No need for jQuery's wonderfulness here.*

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this way

```
<option id="opt7" class='select_continent' data-value='7'>Antarctica</option>
```

jquery

```
$('.select_continent').click(function () {
alert($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Good luck !!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.select_continent').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```