# Getting an element's `id` attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you get the `id` attribute of a html tag using jQuery or without?

For example:

```
<ul id="todo" />
```

How can I get the `id`, without using `jQuery("#todo")`?

Is there a way for that? Will `attr()` work?

Comment: Thank you so much! ^_^ I know that there is a way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: how to get the value of id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618209/jquery-how-to-get-the-value-of-id-attribute)

Comment: @FelixKling: That isn't relevant in the slightest :/

Comment: What is the actual situation? Are you asking how to isolate an element where you won't know its ID? Or are you asking once you have an element, how to get its ID?

Comment: @Matt: Oops, it seems I haven't read the answers thoroughly... but in any case, given this information, the solution is using `attr` and that is covered by at least 2 other questions I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, you most probably need to attach a selector class to the **ul** so that you can use it to get the id:

```
<ul id="todo" class="todoclassname" />
```

then, you can get the id by doing:

```
$(".todoclassname").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `attr('id')` in jQuery or the `id` property (or `getAttribute('id')`) on the native DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.class')[0].id` or `$('.class').get(0).id`

If you need this for multiple elements do

```
$('.class').each(function() {
    this.id
}
```

You can also use conventional `.attr` but it's slower. Though difference is not major, I don't see any drawbacks and syntax is basically same, unless you need to chain-edit attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `.attr('id')` to get the id of an element

Comment: just wondering, what will .attr('id') be invoked on since when using jquery you would either have to do:

    $("#todo").attr("id");

or

    $(".someuniqueclassnameattachedtotodoelement").attr("id");

to get the id

Comment: @JohnGathogo: Not necessarily, you can retrieve the element using any combination of the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) methods (e.g. `$('.foo > ul')` could potentially retrieve the `ul`.

Comment: @Matt: Wont that require you to have some other element with the class "foo"? If not, then I have learnt something new :)

Comment: @JohnGathogo: Yeah, but I don't see what the problem with that is? :S

Answer (score 0):

This can be an option

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].id
```

Also the `attributes` property can help:

```js
const list = document.querySelector("ul");
console.log(list.attributes.id)
```