# store HTML tag attribute value in a variable using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an application using JQuery. This is a fragment of the HTML code I am using:

```
<MarkNag class="altcheckboxoff" id="markable_38" Azpimark_id="100038">helburua </MarkNag>    
<MarkNag class="altcheckboxoff" id="markable_2"  Azpimark_id="100002">Oriolek </MarkNag>
<MarkNag class="altcheckboxoff" id="markable_39" Azpimark_id="100039">gas liberalizazioa </MarkNag>
```

I have the next JQuery script in the HTML page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $("MarkNag").click(function (){
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
   });
</script>
```

I would like to know how could I store "markable_39" in a variable if this MarkNag tag was clicked. I guess I should use .data(). But I dont really know how. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an element's `id` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753560/getting-an-elements-id-attribute) and [get an element's id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id) and probably many others...

Comment: `this` refers to a DOM element. You can access a DOM element's ID with `this.id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```
$("MarkNag").click(function () 
 {
       $(this).toggleClass("highlight");

       var IdOfTag = this.id;
       //or
       IdOfTag = $(this).attr('id');  

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can just use `this.id`,
like:

```
var id = this.id;
```

Comment: True, and somewhat simpler. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the correct code would be `$(this).attr("id")`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just habit to wrap it in $(this). I commented on nymous's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("MarkNag").click(function (){
   $(this).toggleClass("highlight");

   alert(this.id);               // Method 1: this.id
   alert($(this).attr('id'));    // Method 2: $(this).attr('id')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**here u will get object from where the event occurs**

```
var eventobject = arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0];
```

**here u can access any attribute of currentTarget (in this case id)**

```
var id = $(eventobject.currentTarget).attr("id");
```