# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'extraMenuItems.length')

Tags: javascript, html

In web browser I have the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'extraMenuItems.length')

It is code for file manager - the problem is with folder - when I create the folder in the file manager I can't do anything with this. With for example .zip files problem is not showing.

In the code I see missing comma separator, and I add this, but not result

```
// replace any items for overwriting (plugins)
if (extraMenuItems.length > 0)
{
    items = JSON.parse(extraMenuItems);
    for (i in items)
    {
        // setup click action on menu item
        eval("items['" + i + "']['action'] = " + items[i]['action']);
    }
};
```

Comment: where the `extraMenuItems` value is obtained, make sure there is a value

Comment: Hi @SofyanThayf
yes it is :
`extraMenuItems = $(this).attr('dtextramenuitems');`

Comment: `dtextramenuitems` is not a DOM attribute. Maybe this example relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618209/jquery-how-to-get-the-value-of-id-attribute

Comment: imo here it's okay - because : `$(this).val()` i have `extraMenuItems = $(this).attr('dtextramenuitems');`

Answer (score 0):

test the type of extraMenuItems, or wrap your code in a try catch.

```
if (Array.isArray(extraMenuItems) && extraMenuItems.length > 0) {
    items = JSON.parse(extraMenuItems);
    for (i in items)
    {
        // setup click action on menu item
        eval("items['" + i + "']['action'] = " + items[i]['action']);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi,
it's work but only in the part... :)
Now on the folder right mouse click work, but not show properly folder name - folder name it's "test" but right click show "undefined" - and still I can't open the folder.

Comment: in that case, you need to ensure that `extraMenuItems` exists, which isn't present in your question.

Comment: imo it's exist, can you check this ?
https://pastebin.com/veK0s6S9
It's full code from this file.

Comment: i'm afraid the url you posted is hosted in a private network, i can't access it.

Comment: hmm no, it's public access - pastebin - file have a lot of code, so I can't add this here :(

Comment: could you please share the code here https://codeshare.io/? thx.

Comment: i still don't see what  `$(this).attr('dtextramenuitems')` is. but i'm pretty much sure the problem is because `extraMenuItems` isn't what you expected. try print `$(this).attr('dtextramenuitems')`, it's undefined.

Comment: I don't know good Java.. maybe you have some idea how to fix this?